# How can I workaround Path too long exception in c# during WebClient.DownloadFile

Tags: c#, exception, webclient

I get an exception when I try to download file using `webClient.DowloadFile`.

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
Uri downloadUri = new Uri("http://ia.mediaimdb.com/images/M/MV5BMjA5MTE1MjQyNV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwODI4NDMwNw@@._V1._SY0.jpg");            
string posterFilePath = 
           "D:\Visual Studio Projects\Projects\TFS Source Control\" +
           "MyMovieManager\MyMoviesManager\MyMoviesManager\bin\Debug\" +
           "MoviesDB\Journey.2.The.Mysterious.Island.2012.DVDRip.XviD-DEPRiVED[ExtraTorrent]\" +
           "Journey.2.The.Mysterious.Island.2012.DVDRip.XviD-DEPRiVED[ExtraTorrent].png";
webClient.DownloadFile(downloadUri, posterFilePath);
```

I found other cases that this exception was thrown and *my solution was to use functions from kernel32* and write other functions that will replace the File and Path functions.

Is there something that I can do about DownloadFile function?

Comment: Instead of trying to use someething beyond your knowlege just short the path.  Of course trying to get help to pirate a movie is unwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use webclient.DownloadFile to a temp file, i.e. C:\Temp\myDownload.png , then move it to the path you want. you will need to check whether the c:\Temp folder exists. if not, create it.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [LongPathFile class from the BCL project](http://bcl.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Long%20Path&referringTitle=Home), and write to the resulting stream manually.  This will require using [DownloadData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xz398a3f.aspx) instead of `DownloadFile`, and managing the file writing yourself.

Comment: I also used your links to create the move function that will work with the long path. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

One thing to notice is that this exception will also be raised if the address to the file (the first argument) is too long, if you use the version of the function that accepts 2 strings.
Naturally the solution is to convert it to a `Uri` using `new Uri(address)`.